# Go - how to install the package as instructed by go-ui

Tags: go

Trying to use https://github.com/visualfc/go-ui, but the following step is failing.

```
C:\>go get github.com/visualfc/go-ui
package github.com/visualfc/go-ui: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more de
tails see: go help gopath
```

or

```
$ go get github.com/visualfc/go-ui
can't load package: package github.com/visualfc/go-ui: no Go source files in /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/visualfc/go-ui
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't set GOPATH. See http://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH and https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/GOPATH for info.

Comment: From the readme: "This project is closed." and aside from the readme, nothing has been updated in the past 2 years. Are you sure you want to use this?

Comment: Piggy-backing on what @Cubic mentioned. It's worth investigating something that is actively maintained. This SO question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781341/which-gui-toolkit-for-go-language

Comment: Have a look at Gustavo Niemeyer's QML package: http://godoc.org/github.com/niemeyer/qml  As far as I'm aware, the API isn't yet stable (might introduce breaking changes), but he does good work and there's a lot of attention being given to this package.

Answer (score 0):

From the example in the readme, you should go get the package as per what is imported, which in this case is:

```
import (
    "github.com/visualfc/go-ui/ui"
)
```

To get that package, use this command:

```
go get github.com/visualfc/go-ui/ui
```